# Does fontspec have a cache?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

The mininimal working example is the following one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xunicode}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
0123456789
\textbf{\emph{0123456789}}
\end{document}
```

The 6 in italic and bold is like a 0. I wrote a report of bug on http://sourceforge.net/p/linuxlibertine/bugs/190/. The problem should be solved but I installed a new version, and tried again: the problem is still here.

The only solution I see is that fontspec has a cache, but I don't see any information on the documentation file.

I run with xetex.

Comment: Which version of Linux Libertine do you actually have installed?

Comment: You probably still have the old version installed and XeTeX is picking it, what OS you are running and how did you install the font?

Comment: I have installed the 5.3.0 version on http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxlibertine/files/linuxlibertine/5.3.0/

Comment: It's quite possible that XeTeX is picking the font from a different location; the usual way to see this is to call `xelatex --output-driver "xdvipdfmx -vv" <filename>` that will show on the console the location of the used font files.

Comment: I made your test : I have the good fileparth.

Comment: Something strange : I have dowloaded the files 5.3.0, but the information window (on mac, but cmd+I) tell me it's 5.1.2

Comment: @Maieul What file are you asking information on? Is it in `/Library/Fonts`? I usually simply copy in my `/Library/Fonts` whatever I find in the `fonts/opentype` tree in TeX Live, so not to have problems with `xdvipdfmx` choosing a different font.

Comment: Hum, that is my output with "xdvipdfmx --vv"

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GxCErLqp

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a font-bug which has been solved in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, with the help of french user of LaTeX and of the author of fontspec, I found the problem.

In fact, the bug was corrected on the *RBI variant but not in the *RZI which was loaded ...

Comment: This is mostly unhelpful, I'm afraid.

Comment: Of course, it 's unhelpful, because the problem is not in any system of cache...

Comment: Ok, it seem the problem is more complexe.

Comment: See my answer bottom

Comment: finally, it's truelly a bug in the font... which was not solved, even if the author said it was.

Comment: So, I made a fork, to correct temporaly this bug. http://geekographie.maieul.net/Linux-Libertine-chiffre

Comment: http://geekographie.maieul.net/Linux-Libertine-chiffres is the right url